# A better way to let Django SplitDateTimeField accept an empty time field?

Tags: python, django

I like to have the date part of a SplitDateField to be required, but the time part - if left empty - defaults to some value ('00:00:00').

By now, i monkey patch that into the Fields clean() method. Is there a better way to do that? A more "Django-like" way?

Looks like this now (in a forms.py):

```
def mp_clean(self, value):
    # time is in value[1] of a split-datetime field:
    field_value = value[1]
    if field_value in self.empty_values:
        value[1] = '00:00:00'
    return self.mp_original_clean(value)

class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
    super(MyModelAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    that_field = self.fields['that_field']


    if isinstance(that_field,forms.SplitDateTimeField):
        that_field.mp_original_clean = that_field.clean
        that_field.clean = types.MethodType(mp_clean, that_field)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass the split date time field widget, override the clean method, then use the [`widget`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) attribute on your model form to use your widget.

Comment: Very close: There is no clean() on widgets - but it pointed me to the right direction:
Subclassing AdminSplitDateTime and overriding value_from_datadict(). Thank you!

Comment: @devlanger Could you provide an example of how you did this?